# Is there any way that ruby's `create!` can make multiple objects at once?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a system that occasionally spits out 2 objects.  Is there any magic to `create!` that would allow it to create two objects?  E.G. if I say

```
self.class.create! make_up_attributes
```

and `make_up_attributes` passes a 2 item hash, can this create 2 objects of type `self`?

(note, `create` is probably an ActiveRecord method, in Rails)

Comment: You do not require a single SQL query is that it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yep, simply pass in an Array of attribute hashes, like so:

```
self.class.create!([{:name => "John", :age => 26},
                    {:name => "Fred", :age => 50}])
```

See the [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods/create)

Comment: mm...  i thought google would have revealed it if in docs.  Thanks.

Comment: @NewAlexandria Google hits old versions of the docs too often. The best way to go is to go to http://api.rubyonrails.org and search. The first search result for `create` was http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-create which explains what you wanted clearly with examples.